# White spaces are not considered when searching in a string in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a script to find the string "xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxx: "

The problem is that for some reason, Google Scripts is actually looking for "xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxx:". Without the last white space. I have other searches in place in the same script working fine, even with the white space in the end. I tried using str.indexOf() and  str.search() and they all returned the same wrong result.

I am now using the following function that I created because I thought that this would solve the problem, but it didn't:

```
function findchargroup(char,text,startposition)
{
  var charsize = char.length;
  var textsize = text.length;
  var compare="";
  for (var i=startposition;i<textsize;i++)
  {
    for (var k=i;k<(i+charsize);k++)
    {
     compare = compare+text[k]
    }
    if(compare == char)
    {
      return i
    }
    else
    {
      compare=""
    }
  } 
}
```

Any idea of what is happening?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide an example that show's how it's not working [mcve]

Comment: Can you share the code that is giving you the problem? Which function are you using that finds the string you are putting in with a trailing space?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function findchargroup(char,text,startposition) {
  var text=text|| 'Bend over and kiss your xxx good bye. ';
  var char=char|| 'bye. ';
  var startposition=startposition || 0;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(text.indexOf(char,startposition),'Result',-1);//result is 33
}
```

This also works:

```
function findchargroup(char,text,startposition) {
  var text=text|| 'Bend over and kiss your xxx good bye. ';
  var char=char|| 'bye. ';
  var startposition=startposition || 0;
  for(var i=startposition;i<text.length-char.length+1;i++) {
    if(char==text.slice(i,i+char.length)) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(i,'Result',-1);//result is 33
    }
  }
}
```